# In IDA, cannot find xrefs to string in ARM little-endian bootloader/firmware

Tags: ida, binary-analysis, arm

In this [firmware](https://github.com/ExtReMLapin/Foretrex601_Research/raw/master/Unknown.bin) that is ARM Little endian.

There is two strings :

```
0x00006953 : Foretrex 701
0x00006960 : Foretrex 601
```

The issue, is there is no direct Xreft to any of thoses strings ?

For the firmware, it's pretty much the same.

[image]

As IDA cannot find the entry point, to start analyzing the binary (after setting CPU to arm little endian) select all the code (with CTRL+SHIFT+PAGE_DOWN) press C, then "Analyze"

[image]

Comment: Do you know what is the base address of the firmware ?

Comment: No at all, first time I open up a ARM binary (or even a firmware) in IDA, should I get the adresses of all the strings, compare it to the known pointers and try to find an offset that matches the most possible (if not "all") strings ? Or is there a better way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in one of the answers, it's because of the base address, I used [rbasefind](https://github.com/sgayou/rbasefind) to find the base_address of the firmware, and edited it to find the address of the bootloader as there was only two strings plus 11 false string positives.